# TypeORM don't inserting current timestamp

Tags: javascript, mysql, next.js, typeorm

I'm using NextJs with TypeORM adapter for MySQL for auth.

On firt insert on any table the timestamps are ok. If I insert a second one or more they are saved as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

Selects look like this:

```
'1', 'Google', '2023-09-29 00:19:19', '2023-09-29 00:19:19'
'2', 'Microsoft', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Codes:

```
// Companies.ts

@Entity()
export class Companies {
  @Column("int", { primary: true, name: "id", unique: true })
  id: number;

  @Column("varchar", { name: "name", length: 200 })
  nome: string;

  @Column("timestamp", { name: "createdAt", nullable: false })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column("timestamp", { name: "updatedAt", nullable: false })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

```
// createUser.js
export default async function createUser(req = NextRequest, res = NextResponse) {
    let nomeEmpresa = req.body.companyName

    AppDataSource.initialize().then(async data => {
        console.log('==========  Succesfully connected! =========')
        
        // variable for some functions.
        let empresa = await companies.insert({
                name: companyName
            }).then(companyData => {
                return companyData
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                res.status(400).json({'response': 'Error.'})
            })
     }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
     })
}
```

I tried to add default timestamps like `@Column("timestamp", { name: "createdAt", nullable: false, default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })`, but TypeORM returns the error "cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity.".

Also using @CreateDateColumn() and @UpdateDateColumn() instead @Column for timestamps returns same error.

Comment: Have you tried using `@UpdateDateColumn`? Checkout [this guide](https://www.kindacode.com/snippet/typeorm-adding-created_at-and-updated_at-columns/).

Comment: Oh I just noticed you said you did. Please try to clean up the `dist` or `build` and rerun (after using the decorators). It might be that the file has not been recompiled.

Comment: @zouabi I just figured out that the update error is normal cuz the entities obviously doesn't exists on creation.
About timestamp, I cleaned the .next by cleanDistDir and manually and I rebuild it and doesn't work.

Comment: SOLVED. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` was not setted by default in MySQL's table.